# condition as string inside PHP output buffer

Tags: php

I am using `ob_start` to set some content and write these contents to a file.

```
function get_some_contents(){
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <div class="test">
        <?php if( isset( $test ) ){
            echo 'Sample text';
        }?>
    </div>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

I need the content in the function to write to a php file. But when i write the contents, the `if condition` is not written into file. Instead it is executed there itself. 
Is there any way other than storing it in a variable so that the if condition is added directly to buffer without executing it ?

Comment: `escape output`

Comment: @u_mulder didn't get you. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: Make `<?` as `&lt;?` and etc

Comment: Is there any other way ?

Comment: Anyway `<` is part of html tag. To see it as `<` on the page it __must be converted to html-entity__

Comment: @u_mulder And you think outputting `&lt;?php` instead of `<?php` will result in delayed PHP processing of the `<?php` directive. When? After it is written to the output stream? I cannot see how.

Comment: @RonaldAaronson read the question. OP needs to output line of php code as code and not execute it.

Comment: @u_mulder I read it. I am just wondering whether using an entity code would ever result in it being interpreted as a PHP directive.

Comment: But why would you use the output buffer?

Comment: @Jerodev I am creating a template which should be called and executed at a later point. I initially used to store this to a variable as `$test.='<?php if();'` and saved this variable content to a file which was too difficult to manage and maintain

Comment: @um_mulder I think that before you returned the code, you would have to first do a string replacement replacing `&lt;` with `<`. So you could just as well use some other characters other than `<?php` and '?>` to delineate PHP code, such as 'START_PHP` and `END_PHP` and replace these respectively with `<?php` and '?>` before returning.

Comment: Why are you dynamically writing this from PHP code in the first place? Can’t you put this into its own file which you can read with `file_get_contents` if needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, yes, you're using actual PHP tags, which will cause PHP to get interpreted. Use literally *anything else* to avoid that:

```
function get_some_contents(){
    return <<<'EOD'
        <div class="test">
            <?php if( isset( $test ) ){
                echo 'Sample text';
            }?>
        </div>
EOD;
}
```

```
function get_some_contents(){
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <div class="test">
        <?= '<?php'; ?> if( isset( $test ) ){
            echo 'Sample text';
        }?>
    </div>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Put this into `template.php`:

```
<div class="test">
    <?php if( isset( $test ) ){
        echo 'Sample text';
    }?>
</div>
```

And read it from there using `file_get_contents` or similar as needed.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to not use `<?php` and `?>` tags in the code but rather stand-ins `START_PHP` and `END_PHP`, which have no meaning to PHP. But before returning the code to the caller, do the necessary text substitution replacing these pseudo-directives with the real thing:

```
<?php

function get_some_contents(){
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <div class="test">
        START_PHP if( isset( $test ) ){
            echo 'Sample text';
        }END_PHP
    </div>
    <?php
    $code = ob_get_clean();
    $code = str_replace('START_PHP', '<?php', $code);
    $code = str_replace('END_PHP', '?>', $code);
    return $code;
}
```